# Directory structure - best practices

Tags: javascript, html, css, image

So far I've got:

```
/css
/img
/js
```

But what about the raw files and WIP stuff? (raw footage, photoshop and illustrator files...)

I thought about **resources** but that's kinda long and I'd like to keep it short and neat like the other 3 folders.

I know there really isn't a convention but what do you guys use/recommend?

Thanks!

Comment: If resources is too long, name it res !

Answer (score 1):

I keep my raw files separate of my application directory. That way I don't accidentally upload them when pushing the app! I make a new folder on my computer that says "Original Files" then a subfolder "XYZ App" with the files.

Answer (score 0):

If I'm actually putting this stuff in a repo, and I don't want it exposed to any users on the web, I'll create an /assets folder and use .htaccess to limit access. But you'll want to be judicious with the number of assets you're managing in a repo. It wouldn't be nice to ask someone else to clone a 2GB repo with most of it being binary assets they don't need :)